# Git binary file conflict in two branches

Tags: git, git-branch

This probably has been solved before but I could not find the solution.
I have two branches master and localdev.

There is a gif file that I just opened and committed long back in branch b. Now when I try to either delete it and merge it from master, it does not work(probably due to the changes being committed).I have other changes in that commit which I do not want to revert back.

Is there a way to revert this single file as it exist on master and show in localdev?

diff for the same file on both branches shows

```
index 3288d10..c97ba49 100644
Binary files a/temp/spinner2.gif and b/temp/spinner2.gif differ
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for "git checkout branch_name -- filepath".

This command can throw away your changes to a particular file in your current branch.

So if you want to get that gif file from your master branch while being in the localdev branch, use this command (keep in mind, **this deletes the changes you made to the gif in localdev**):

```
git checkout master -- path/to/your/file/spinner2.gif
```

Make sure to include that double hyphen and the path to the gif.

Comment: I tried that. I am not sure what checkout the same file in master should do. It does not revert the changes and shows the same differences of index.

Comment: The `checkout` command writes it into the index/staging-area and your work-directory, as if you had done a copy from a completely separate checkout of the other branch and `git add`-ed the file.  That means it's *ready* to commit to your current (`localdev`) branch, but it's not yet committed there.  So `git status` will show it as modified and ready-to-commit, and `git diff --cached` will tell you "binary files differ", and so on.

Comment: What @torek said. So basically, @startedFromTheBottom, I'm guessing you're seeing 
`Changes to be committed: modified: path/to/your/file/spinner2.gif` when you type "git status". If you commit this change, you're setting it back to what the gif is saved as on master. From that point on, the diff should be empty.